How can I print with c#/WPF images with high resolution
With WPF/C# printing is only in 96dpi. How can I print bitmaps with e.g. 200dpi?
Here is my pseudocode:
var document = new PrintDocument
{
    PrintSettings = _settings,
    PageCount = 1
}

document.PrintPage += (sender, e) =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine("print pageSize " + e.pageSize + " "+ e.Graphics .DPI + "dpi");
    ...
    var rect1= new Rectangle(0,0,e.pageSize.Width,e.pageSize.Height);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(image1, rect1);
}

document.Print();

My problem is, e.pageSize is for A4 always 793x1122 and e.Graphics.DPI is 96. But I want it bigger, so that the image1, which is bigger, is not losing quality.

On approach would be to first render each page to a RenderTargetBitmap using high DPI settings in the constructor arguments (e.g. 300 DPI) and then print that

See the "PageResolution" class. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing.printticket.pageresolution?view=windowsdesktop-9.0

The solution is actually easy. Just to scale up the Visual, to get more pixels to render in. The dpi will still be 96, but I can ignore this.
Problem with this was, that the PageSize also went up.
But I found another constructor for DocumentPage in the DocumentPaginator-class to specify the original page size with the bigger visual and like this it works.
using swd = System.Windows.Documents;

public override swd.DocumentPage GetPage(int pageNumber)
{
    var factor = 3f;
    
    var page = new Canvas
    {
        Handler = Handler,
        PageNumber = pageNumber,
        Width = ImageableArea.Width * factor,
        Height = ImageableArea.Height * factor,
        LayoutTransform = new swm.ScaleTransform(1 / factor, 1 / factor)   // this is scaling the output on the paper
    };

    var rect = new sw.Rect(new sw.Point(ImageableArea.X, ImageableArea.Y), ImageableArea.Size);
    page.Measure(ImageableArea.Size);
    page.Arrange(rect);
    page.UpdateLayout();

    // 17.12.24 VERY IMPORTANT, if we scale the canvas by factor, we would also get a bigger pagesize
    // so we need to specify the original pagesize in the ctor here:
    var docpage = new swd.DocumentPage(page, ImageableArea.Size, rect, rect);
    return docpage;
}

